# SQL query that extracts a topic keyword from article titles

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query like this to select the only row with title contains specific programming topics.

```
SELECT
    posted_date,
CASE
    WHEN LOWER(title) LIKE "%c#%" THEN "c#"
    WHEN LOWER(title) LIKE "%c++%" THEN "c++"
    .
    .
    .
    WHEN LOWER(title) LIKE "%sql%" THEN "sql"
    ELSE ""
END AS single_topics
FROM
    article_data
WHERE
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM posted_date) = 2018
```

It's working fine but I wonder that can `WHEN` in `CASE` part be shortened in case of a lot of topics to choose?

Sample data in `title` column (they are like article title).

```
The fastest way to do x in C++.
Things most people get wrong about JavaScript.
How to send android push notification using cURL.
macOS Mojave - Features, Specifications and more.
What is map, filter and reduce function in Python and how to use them?
```

Comment: Also, can you provide sample `title` values? I'm curious to see how they're formed, that can help answerers as well.

Comment: Is it intent that he first match wins?

Comment: @202_accepted I've added sample value in `title` column. It's more like an article title.

Comment: @aventurin Yes, the first match wins.

Comment: @phwt So I would recommend using a Full-Text Search of some sort, with Google BigQuery I'm not sure what that looks like, but this Stack Overflow post looks like it has 
info on it: [Does Google BigQuery support Full-Text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264868/does-google-bigquery-support-full-text-search)